Storing numbers 0-9 in a column
I need to store the numbers 0-9 in a Mysql column. Each row may contain one or more of these numbers. Numbers may be in any order and appear only once per row.
Is there an efficient way of doing this that i don't know?
I thought about using one column per number but that seems excessive? I also thought about creating a table for these values and using junction table, but it also seems excessive somehow.
There's >100 rows of data being generated every year but a lot of select queries on them.
Mock-up data structure:
Products



product
store(this is the structure in question)




Product 1
1,2,3


Product 2
5,2,2



Loading (ingested from an external API)



product
weight
store




Product 1
324
3


Product 1
43
2


Product 2
22
1



My SQL query will need to fetch all rows from the Loading table that has a store-number correlating to the product. See the following pseudo-query
Select * from Loading where Loading.store in Products.store
Running on MariaDB 10.9.3

What's your version of MySQL? Please always include this with your questions!

Does the digits order makes sense? I'd prefer VARCHAR(10) due to your conditions - and if the ordering makes sense than this is the only reasonable solution (40-bit BCD-encoded binary is the next option).

Have you considered the SET data type? Allows unique values. But, the data will be of string type.  Lots of select queries and joins is another consideration. How much data and what kind of queries - details can help with the design.

Do you need to write queries that filter based on this data and / or manipulate it, or this data will only always be used for display purposes?

@J.D. I need to select rows from another table that has a single digit column that matches any of the ones represented in the first table. If i have 3,4 and 5 in my column i need to have a clause that is somewhat like ´WHERE digit IN (3,4,5)` on the second table for example.

@Akina digits order are not significant.

digits order are not significant Add this to the question text - this may be critical. Also provide complete list of the operations which would be performed over these values.

Can a digit be repeated?  For example, can there be two 3's?  Is there any order to the digits?  Can the first digit be 0?

Let's see some of the queries.


I need to select rows from another table that has a single digit column that matches any of the ones represented in the first table. If i have 3,4 and 5 in my column i need to have a clause that is somewhat like ´WHERE digit IN (3,4,5)` on the second table for example.


However it needs to be matched against another table that generates 250k rows a year though

Joining or using this data in a WHERE clause means you'll be using it as part of a predicate. Predicates lose sargability (the ability to efficiently use an index to serve the predicate of the query) rather easily the more complex their expression becomes, such as when you start denormalizing the way you store the data used in that predicate.
If you care about utmost performance, then the best thing to do is store this data normalized in a separate table, with a one-to-many relationship with your main table, indexed appropriately. It's not overkill regardless of how small your main table is, especially in a relational database like MySQL, which is meant to operate on rows and tables.
Yes, your main table is tiny, and your other table with 250,000 rows being added to it each year, isn't necessarily that big either. But there'll definitely be a measurable difference in performance between when your query needs to scan your entire main table (denormalized implementation) 250,000 times vs only needing to seek directly to the couple of rows that satisfy your predicate (using an index on the normalized data) - especially as your secondary table grows larger each year.

Allthough it saddens me seeing people failing to normalize, may we assume you meant denormalizing instead of demoralizing? ;)

@peter Hah! Dang auto-correct. Thanks! And agreed it saddens me too.

I tried this with MySQL 8.0.34 and hope its useful.
CREATE TABLE products (
  pid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  store SET('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') -- can include upto 9
);

INSERT INTO products 
  VALUES 
    ('p1', '0,5'), 
    ('p2', '0,1,2,3,6'), 
    ('p3', '1');

Note the usage of SET type, which is a string.
Some example queries on products:
SELECT * FROM products WHERE FIND_IN_SET('0', store)>0;
SELECT * FROM products WHERE FIND_IN_SET(0, store)>0;
SELECT * FROM products WHERE store LIKE '%2%';
SELECT * FROM products WHERE store = '0,5';

Note the usage of FIND_IN_SET function with the first and second queries, above.
CREATE TABLE loading (
  pid VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  store int
);

INSERT INTO loading 
  VALUES 
    ('p2', 3), 
    ('p2', 5), 
    ('p2', 6), 
    ('p1', 0);

A query using both tables:
SELECT p.pid ppid, p.store pstore, l.pid lpid, l.store lstore
  FROM  loading l
  INNER JOIN products p 
  ON l.pid = p.pid AND FIND_IN_SET(l.store, p.store)>0
  WHERE
    l.pid = 'p2';

Outputs:
+------+-----------+------+--------+
| ppid | pstore    | lpid | lstore |
+------+-----------+------+--------+
| p2   | 0,1,2,3,6 | p2   |      3 |
| p2   | 0,1,2,3,6 | p2   |      6 |
+------+-----------+------+--------+


Note: MariaDB has a SET data type and it can be used similarly as shown above along with the FIND_IN_SET function : MariaDB - SET data type.

Excellent proposal, just ran it in a test environment and it works perfectly. Only i'm on MariaDB that does not support SET :(


I thought about using one column per number but that seems excessive?

A BIT column per number seems a quite reasonable possibility, based on what you describe.
I'm not familiar with MySQL internals offhand, but in other SQL engines, multiple bit columns in one table are commonly packed together, so it is extremely efficient with storage.

There's >100 rows of data being generated every year

A hundred rows a year is not significant, but I wonder whether you meant 100k a year or (significantly) 100m a year?

but a lot of select queries on them. Use cases will be joining data from other tables where that value is stored as a single number in our data lake.

If there are lots of selects involving joins with this data, then eking out the very best performance is likely to involve correct indexing, aligning the data types of the columns being joined, and other very specific fitting to the common queries and the circumstances.
But I wouldn't try to jump the gun. Just try whatever seems the simplest and most straightforward approach to a correct solution first, and then consider whether performance is found acceptable. If not, you'll have a concrete scenario with code artefacts that you can share with an expert for advice, and who can try a variety of transformations that might improve performance.
With any data processing whose volumes and performance expectations will potentially tax the limitations of the hardware, there are generally just too many variables to be able to plan any specific solution.

No it's below one hundred each year. However it needs to be matched against another table that generates 250k rows a year though

@jared, all very modest for standard PC hardware. I don't think you'll have any trouble with it.
